# wordpress upgrading and plugin updating issue after changing host

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress

Some months ago I changed my wordpress website from my previous host to a new host, and it has been transferred properly and working fine. But some days after I'm facing this unsual problem that I can't solve by my own:

Whenever I try to upgrade my wordpress version or even try to update my plugins, after waiting for a really long time, my site shows this message:

> An automated WordPress update has failed to complete.

How can I fix this issue, so that I can update my site like before?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a .maintenance file in the WP root directory? If so, remove it. Remember, it's invisible, so make sure your invisible files are visible.

That should do it.  If it doesn't, the update directory in your uploads or wp-content folder. Remove it.